# Overload type method?

Tags: c#, methods, overloading

Is there a way to make an **overload of a type method**?

My goal in this particular situation is to make an overload of `string.Substring()` with parameters `start_index` and `end_index`.

Comment: @MitchWheat: That won't help in this case, as there's already an instance method with a matching signature.

Comment: I meant create a new extension method alongside, rather than trying to overload an existing method. I thought that was obvious, but obviously not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No but you can use so called [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) of a `string`:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string SubstringRegion(this string str, int startIndex, int endIndex)
    {
        return str.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Except that there's already an overload of `String.Substring` with two `int` parameters, so this will never be called unless you call it statically as `StringExtensions.Substring(x, y, z)`.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, sure, so we must unfortunately name it a little bit different. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I didn't know anything about **extension methods**. Thanks!